# Set null the next set of N values

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, constraint, binary-variable, logical-constraints

I'm dealing with a problem I already modelled by using linear programming. The already existing constraints set at 1 groups of contiguous variables (for ex: `(0001111100000000000)` ).
I'm now asked to add a constraint that:

- set at 0 at least the next set of N variables
  In the mentioned example, said N = 5 I won't be able to get `(00011111000011110000)`, but I could get `(00011111000000011110)`. What causes me a problem, is that I have groups of 1s and not single placed 1s. If I had just single placed 1s, the constraint would be something similar: $$\sum_{i=0}^{N}x_i=0$$but I can't find a way to formulate the constraint in order to cover all the 1s of the set.

Comment: Not quite clear what you are asking.  Do you mean that you want to avoid 101, 1001, 10001, and 100001?

Comment: Yes, but I can't modelize them: the idea is that "I want that the next N variables after the last 1 of each group of variables set at 1 should be 0"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, what you want to enforce is the following: if $x_i=1$ and $x_{i+1}=0$ (so that variable $i$ is the last in a string of one or more consecutive 1s) then $x_{i+2}=\dots=x_{i+N}=0$ (position $i+1$ is the start of $N$ consecutive 0s). You can do that with the following constraints for each index $j$:
$$x_j \le 1-x_{j-2} + x_{j-1}$$$$x_j \le 1-x_{j-3}+x_{j-2}$$$$\vdots$$$$x_j \le 1-x_{j-N}+x_{j-N+1}.$$Omit any constraints for which the variable being subtracted on the right does not exit. For instance, if $N=5$ and $j=4$ you would have the first two constraints, but the third constraint would subtract $x_0,$ which doesn't exist, so you stop after two constraints.

Comment: Thanks, in this case j starts from i, right?

Comment: No, $j$ starts from 3. So you get one constraint for $j=3$ (if $x_1=1$ and $x_2=0$ then $x_3$ has to be 0), two constraints for $x_4$ (has to be 0 if either $x_1=1$ and $x_2=0$ or $x_2=1$ and $x_3=0$), three constraints for $x_5$, and four for $x_6$ onward (assuming $N=5$).

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t get the mechanism for the initial value of $j$: assuming to have $A=50$ variables in total, $N=5$ variables that should be 0 after the last 1, $j$ will start from $N-1$?

Comment: Assuming you want five consecutive zeros any time a group of 1s of any length (including just a single 1) ends, then the first time you would need to enforce this would be if $x_1=1$ and $x_2=0$, after which you would need to force $x_3$ to be 0. So $j$ would start at 3.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid $101$, the logical proposition is
$$\lnot (x_i \land \lnot x_{i+1} \land x_{i+2}).$$
Rewriting in conjunctive normal form yields
$$\lnot x_i \lor x_{i+1} \lor \lnot x_{i+2},$$
which you can enforce via linear constraint
$$(1-x_i) + x_{i+1} +(1-x_{i+2}) \ge 1,$$
equivalently,
$$x_i - x_{i+1} + x_{i+2} \le 1.$$
More generally, to avoid $10\dots01$ (with $n$ zeroes), impose
$$x_i - \sum_{j=i+1}^{i+n} x_j + x_{i+n+1} \le 1.$$

---

Rather than impose separate constraints to avoid 101, 1001, 10001, and 100001, @prubin suggested instead enforcing
$$(x_i \land \lnot x_{i+1}) \implies \bigwedge_{j=i+2}^{i+n} \lnot x_j.$$
Now rewrite in conjunctive normal form to somewhat automatically derive the desired linear constraints:
$$
\lnot (x_i \land \lnot x_{i+1}) \lor \bigwedge_{j=i+2}^{i+n} \lnot x_j \\
(\lnot x_i \lor x_{i+1}) \lor \bigwedge_{j=i+2}^{i+n} \lnot x_j \\
\bigwedge_{j=i+2}^{i+n} (\lnot x_i \lor x_{i+1} \lor \lnot x_j) \\
\bigwedge_{j=i+2}^{i+n} ((1 - x_i) + x_{i+1} + (1 - x_j) \ge 1) \\
\bigwedge_{j=i+2}^{i+n} (x_i - x_{i+1} + x_j \le 1),
$$
which is equivalent to what @prubin recommended.

Comment: Thanks! Literally what I was trying to achieve

Comment: @RobPratt, Would you please, is there any rule to move indexed logical and, $\bigwedge_{j=i+2}^{i+n}$, from the right to the left side of the third expression?

Comment: @A.Omidi It is the distributive property: $P \lor (Q \land R)$ is equivalent to $(P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$

Comment: @RobPratt, Thanks. 

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, I have a question regarding a sequence of binary variables. Suppose we have an array of binary variables $\{x_{i}, \quad \forall i \in I \}$. If we want to define a condition as: if any of $x_{i} = 1$ then the rest of the bigger indices should be one, e.g. if the card of index $I$ would be six then $\{0,0,1,1,1,1\}$, is it possible to write that as: $ ((x_{i} \implies(x_{j} \land x_{k})) \bigvee  (x_{j} \implies(\lnot x_{i} \land x_{k})) \bigvee (x_{k} \implies(\lnot x_{i} \land \lnot x_{j}))) \quad \forall i,j,k \in I: (i\lt j \lt k)$?

Comment: @A.Omidi I would instead express it as $x_i \implies x_{i+1}$.

Comment: or just as a simple case, we write that as: $((x_{i} \land x_{k}) \implies(x_{j}))  \quad \forall i,j,k \in I: (i\lt j \lt k)$

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, as far as I test $x_{i} \implies x_{i+1}$ can sort from the first position to ensure contiguity. May I have your insight?

Comment: Your latter proposal enforces contiguous ones but allows $0\dots01\dots10\dots0$.

Comment: and about the first one I wrote, do you mean it is incorrect?

Comment: @A.Omidi Better to start a new question rather than discuss in the comments of this existing question.

Comment: Ok. I will add a new one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you have a set of numbers 000011110 and you want to detect the index of the last 1 and then set next N numbers at 0. Obviously your set/list of cardinality 10 isn't like {0001110000} as in that case you already have 0s after the 1s. For the problem to make sense it would be like 0110001110 or 0011000111
If length of the set is known say m then
$\sum_{i=m+1}^N x_{i} \le 2 - (x_m+x_{m-1}) $
and to make it tighter
$\sum_{i=m+1}^N x_{i} \le x_m$

If the length of the set is not known then its a different problem. In that case need to find at what maximum index the last 1 occurs.

Comment: But if $m$ is said to be the set length (of the total variables), how can a variable have the index $i=m+1$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You may have defined set of indices of length $m+n$, of which first $m$ have values of 0 or 1 series, like $x_1,x_2,...x_m$.

Comment: No, if I only define $m$ as the total amount of variables and $N$ the next 0 variables to be set, how would your constraints be?